# how to use watch properly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am sending props `month_id` to child component from parent component by clicking on a `<li>`. My child component code is like below.

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['mosque_id', 'month_id'],
        data(){
            return {
                prayer_times: [],
            }
        },
        watch: {
            month_id() {
                this.getPrayerTime();
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getPrayerTime: function () {
                axios.get('/api/v1/getPrayerTime/'+ this.mosque_id+'/'+ this.month_id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.prayer_times = response.data;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

But I am getting result little late. I have to click twice on `<li>` to get result. Am I using `watch` properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `immediate:true` option to run the watch at the first rendering, also change `function (response) {` to `(response)=> {` in order to get access to `this` :

```js
   watch: {
            month_id: {
              handler(){
                  this.getPrayerTime();
                },
               immediate : true 
            }
        },
    methods:{
            getPrayerTime: function () {
                axios.get('/api/v1/getPrayerTime/'+ this.mosque_id+'/'+ this.month_id)
                .then((response)=> {
                    this.prayer_times = response.data;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks @Boussadjra Brahim. How `immediate : true` will help me ?

Comment: You're welcome, by default the watch doesn't run at the first rendering of the component, so you need to add this option to override that behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the new value in your watch function and send it to yout **getPrayerTime** function

```
watch: {
    month_id(newValue, oldValue): {
        this.getPrayerTime(newValue);
    },
}
```

I think this can help you.